# finding probability of shop stock

Tags: probability

A shop keeper buys a particular kind of light bulbs from three manufacturers denoted A,B and C. She buys $30\%$ of her stock from A, $45\%$ from B and $25\%$ from C. In the past, she has found that $2\%$ of C’s bulbs are faulty whereas only $1\%$ of A’s and B’s are. Suppose that she chooses a bulb at random and it is faulty, what is the probability that it was one of C’s bulbs.

tried answer:$$\frac{0.3\cdot0.02+0.45\cdot0.01+0.25\cdot0.01}{0.02+0.01+0.01}$$
 is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The starting steps should be

$$\begin{align*}
P(C\mid\text{faulty}) &= \frac{P(C\cap\text{faulty})}{P(\text{faulty})}\\
&= \frac{P(C\cap\text{faulty})}{P(A\cap\text{faulty})+P(B\cap\text{faulty}) + P(C\cap\text{faulty})}\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$